# Programmatically duplicate S3 bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, backup

Is there a way to programmatically/automatically duplicate an S3 bucket?

I'm specifically wanting to dot this as a backup method on the off chance a bucket accidentally gets deleted or the S3 account gets hacked somehow.

Ideally I could set it up to run daily automatically.

If there's a way to do it from a Rails app, that'd be nice, but if there's some external service that already provides this functionality, I'd go for that as well.

Comment: To duplicate it locally (i.e. your machine?). The API does allow copying items to other regions, though this wouldn't help you if you were hacked - they could just delete everything, everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ruby gem like [Fog](http://fog.io/1.1.1/index.html) to do this.

There is a [practical example on their website.](http://fog.io/1.1.1/storage/)